# XPath to retrieve name of node within a choice in the Schema

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an xml schema with a complex element containing a choice node:

```
    <xs:complexType name="MemberType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="StandardID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Type2ID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="OtherID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My goal in the end to to have a key value pair with the id type and value from the document. Parsing manually works fine but it would be simpler if there was an XPath way to do this. I assume its a two step xpath retrieve chosen node name then retrieve the value with that name. Assume the the choices node could change.

How can I retrieve the element name such as "Type2ID" using XPath? (Also note that the xsd is external and I cannot change it)

Answer (score 1):

If the containing element is the context item, then you can use `name(*[last()])` to get the name of its last child element.